# dataframes don't merge but concat using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

The thing is when get data from the query and use like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(original_data)
df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer', indicator=False,
                        left_on = query_uniq_col.replace(' ','').split(','),
                        right_on = query_uniq_col.replace(' ','').split(','))
```

in theory, the df should be the merge between df1 and df2, but it turns out that df was the result of the concatenation of df1 and df2. I already try to match the type between df1 and df2 by using

```
for x in df2.columns:
            df1[x]=df1[x].astype(df2[x].dtypes.name)
            print(df1[x].dtypes)
            if str(df1[x].dtypes) == 'float64':
                print('yes')
                df1[x].round(decimals=8)
                df2[x].round(decimals=8)
```

the result doesn't change. If I export those df1 and df2 to csv using `df.to_csv()` then read them back with `df.read_csv()` the merge now is perfect, but the thing is i shouldn't do that. It's cheating, and might cause some failure if it affects other airflow tasks.

The purpose that I wanted to used merge for was to find the differences between the 2 dataframes by using
`df["difference"]= df["gtv_x"] - df["gtv_y"]`
and then I would write the only differences back into database.
please help

Current:

```
df1:
date        city vehicle_type gtv   number_of_bookings
2021-11-07  HCM Car          1000   200
2021-11-06  HN  Truck        2000   300
2021-11-05  LA  6w_truck     3000   400
2021-11-04  CM  mini_van     4000   500

df2:
date        city vehicle_type gtv   number_of_bookings
2021-11-07  HCM Car          1000   200
2021-11-06  HN  Truck        2000   300
2021-11-05  LA  6w_truck     3000   400
2021-11-04  CM  mini_van     9000   500

df:
date        city vehicle_type gtv_x   number_of_bookings_x gtv_y number_of_bookings_y
2021-11-07  HCM  Car          1000    200
2021-11-06  HN   Truck        2000    300
2021-11-05  LA   6w_truck     3000    400
2021-11-04  CM   mini_van     4000    500
2021-11-07  HCM  Car                                       1000    200
2021-11-06  HN   Truck                                     2000    300
2021-11-05  LA   6w_truck                                  3000    400
2021-11-04  CM   mini_van                                  9000    500
```

Expect:

```
date        city vehicle_type gtv_x   number_of_bookings_x gtv_y number_of_bookings_y
2021-11-07  HCM  Car          1000    200                  1000  200
2021-11-06  HN   Truck        2000    300                  2000  300
2021-11-05  LA   6w_truck     3000    400                  3000  400
2021-11-04  CM   mini_van     4000    500                  9000  500
```

Comment: provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...give 2 sample dataframes so that anyone know how your data looks like and perform some testing on it

Comment: @AnuragDabas yeah, i just appended it to the question, thank you for reminding

Comment: What is `query_uniq_col`? Because `df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['date', 'city', 'vehicle_type'])` works

Comment: @HenryEcker it was about spliting the text to get the unique columns' names, even i used like ```on=['date', 'city', 'vehicle_type']```, it still didn't work as expectation

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, although changing the format and style, it didn't work. So i did try to convert the date field in to String, problem got solved. Thank you so much for taking time for me!